# Is it a good practice keeping a class as ultimate base class of the project just like object class of Java

Tags: java

Does any company or project keep its own ultimate base class just like object class of Java from which all the classes of the project extending. Is keeping such an ultimate base class is good practice in Java World? Basically i am from Delphi World where these are common practice.

Thanks in advance
Joy

Comment: how would you enforce this? And what's the added value/feature does this base class provide?

Comment: Currently there is no such purpose. But since we dont know the future...

Comment: It might work for interfaces, since you can add them to any class you create. A base interface to extend from might be usefull in some projects. Again, when you use interfaces from the java libraries they will not extend you your base interface, and when you extend from a java library interface, you can't add your base interface.

Comment: At least in my company's Delphi projects I never saw a project wide base class. What's the use of it?

Comment: if you want to change the color of all the forms/buttons or if you want to add some memory cleaning before destroying objects ?

Comment: Hm, sorry this doesn't make sense. Maybe for some GUI related classes. But you said all classes. This includes e.g. classes with some business logic. Having a method for changing the color in a non GUI class would be counterproductive and violates OO principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None that I know of.

It would, in general, be a bad idea.

For one thing, you'd compromise the insistence every time you *extend* one of the classes in the Java library (e.g. the myriad of formatter-type classes or even a particular calendar implementation extending `java.util.Calendar`) which obviously will not have your firmwide-mandated class as its base.

`java.lang.Object` does the job adequately.